# How to merge two tables to show entries historical changes

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables

**T1**:

| ID | Reference | Status | Event Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Flowers | Dispatched | 2021-12-10 |
| 2 | Flowers | Delivered | 2021-12-11 |

And **T2**:

| ID | Reference | Comments | Event Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Flowers | well done | 2021-12-12 |
| 2 | Flowers | go on | 2021-12-13 |
| 3 | Pot | random | 2021-12-13 |

The table I'm trying to have by querying for **Flowers** reference is (using Postgres)

| t1_ID | t2_ID | Reference | Comments | Status | t1_Event Timestamp | t2_Event Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | Flowers | null | Dispatched | 2021-12-10 | null |
| 2 | null | Flowers | null | Delivered | 2021-12-11 | null |
| null | 1 | Flowers | well done | Delivered | 2021-12-11 | 2021-12-12 |
| null | 2 | Flowers | go on | Delivered | 2021-12-11 | 2021-12-13 |

In other words, I need to have a joined table that records all the update between the two tables.
I tried many queries, like **LEFT JOIN, UNION, etc.** however all attempts are unsuccessful.
Could you suggest me which SQL statements should I use to obtain the expected result?

Comment: What would you like to do exactly? Just display the results of all Flowers references from the two tables in a single one?

Comment: Exactly, however If I use a simple JOIN it will not return the rows in which Comments is null.

Comment: @RDK why is t1_id = 2 for rows from T2? Shouldn't it be NULL?

Comment: @Blue_Elephant Basically for each T1 row I need to check if in T2 there is an entry with the same reference and a LOWER-EQUAL T2_event timestamp

Comment: @Zakaria you are right, I edited it.

Comment: @RDK do all rows from T2 have the status delivered?

Comment: @Zakaria Yes that's because at that T2 Event timestamp, "DELIVERED" is the most recent T1 status for the same reference

Comment: If you are looking for T2 Flowers rows having a lower timestamp than T1, is it correct that you should have no results for the set you gave?

Comment: @RDK oh now I think I understand you. In this case, I think you were correct in the first place when T1_ID weren't null!

Answer (score 0):

Use cte and union

```
with cte as(
   select ID as t1_ID,
          null as t2_ID,
          Reference,
          null as Comments,
          Status,
          Event_Timestamp as t1_Event_Timestamp,
          null as t2_Event_Timestamp,
          row_number() over(partition by Reference order by Reference) seq
    from t1
)

select t1_id,t2_id,reference,comments,status,t1_event_timestamp,t2_event_timestamp  
from cte

union all

select null as t1_ID,
       t2.ID::varchar(10) as t2_ID,
       t2.Reference,
       Comments,
       (select max(Status) from cte t3 where t3.seq = (select max(seq) from cte)) as status,
       (select max(t1_Event_Timestamp) from cte t3 where t3.Reference = t2.Reference) as t1_Event_Timestamp,
       t2.Event_Timestamp as t2_Event_Timestamp
from t1
left join t2 on t1.Reference = t2.Reference
group by t2.ID,t2.Reference,t2.Comments,t2.Event_Timestamp
```

Demo in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4acadc55fb0697ee7c6733cd58c7483d)